# Are init values required for for-loops?

Tags: for-loop, lua

Upon embarking on attempting to learn the basics of Lua, I came across the syntax for a for loop.

```
for init,max/min value, increment
do
   statement(s)
end
```

Now, I'm wondering if an initializing variable is required for it to work, or can you skip it. If it's the latter, how?

I assumed like

```
for ,num,num
```

^, but i'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2):

They are requited. [From the Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5):

> The numeric for loop repeats a block of code while a control variable runs through an arithmetic progression. It has the following syntax:
>
> ```
>   stat ::= for Name ‘=’ exp ‘,’ exp [‘,’ exp] do block end
> ```

Only the part inside `[ ]` can be omitted. So in:

```
for v = e1, e2, e3 do block end
```

Only `e3` is optional (`1` as default):

```
for v = e1, e2 do block end
```